# Google spreadsheet list validation values must vary per row

Tags: javascript, validation, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two columns:
Column A contains the email address
Column B contains the status - a dropdown of valid statuses so the user will not have to type them manually.

Per row:
If a valid email address is entered in column A --> the status in column B can be selected from the dropdown list as s1 or s2.

If a valid email address is *not* entered in column A --> the status in column B can be selected from the dropdown list as s3 or s4.

Obviously the options for values in the dropdown list vary per row.
How can this be accomplished?

For modifying a single list of dropdown values I can use a formula like:

=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isemail(C3),F2:F12,F1))

But the resultant list is constant for **all rows**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the trick. This runs 'onEdit' of anything on the page, so whenever a new user email is entered, it will automatically update the validation for the dropdown menu in each row's B column based on the true/false value of column C (which has a simple =isEmail() formula)

Set up your page:

I assume you have a header row, this script loops starting on row 2:

You have your same column A and B, but in each row of column C write a simple =isEmail() formula that tests the value in column A as true/false.

Then for the dropdown menus, in Column D list the S1 and S2 values, and in Column E, list your S3 and S4 values.  I think you can see how the test works in this script below, let me know if this works! If needed I can give a screenshot of how my page is setup.

```
function onEdit(e){

var ss = e.source;
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

//values will be a 2D array of all the data on the page, in the exact dimensions of that data
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var menu_range;

//this scripts assumes a header row, so the loop starts at 1 instead of 0

for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

    var isEmail = values[i][2];
    var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 1);

    if(isEmail) {

        menu_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D2:D3');

    } else {

        menu_range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('E2:E3');

    }

    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(menu_range).build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

}